# Parsing Twitter API 1.1 JSON

Tags: java, android, json, parsing, twitter

I've been working on an open source code of a Twitter reader (read only) (oauth 2.0) that pulls JSON from a user timeline. It successfully pulls the JSON from Twitter API 1.1. The challenge I'm facing is converting that JSON into something user friendly. I've implemented sections of another source code that focused on parsing the JSON, but I'm not very familiar with parsing JSON. It's patchwork so I know I might be overlooking something. Possibly a redundancy or missing part.

UPDATED:
When I run the app, it doesn't crash, it's just stuck at "Got Token!". What I'm hoping to display is a list of tweets somewhat formatted to look like one. I believe it's the MainActivity, but I could be wrong. You will need a Consumer Key and Secret to test. I'll put up what I have at the moment, but if anyone knows how I can get out of that loop, I'd appreciate your input.

Thanks!

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.readtwitterfeed;


import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Reader;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.params.BasicHttpParams;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONValue;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.readtwitterfeed.R;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

// CONSUMER API KEY - 21 characters (go here to get one: https://dev.twitter.com/apps/)
// **** CHANGE THIS ****
static final String twitterAPIKEY = "@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@";

// CONSUMER SECRET  - 41 characters (go here to get one: https://dev.twitter.com/apps/)
// **** CHANGE THIS ****
static final String twitterAPISECRET = "@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@";

static final String twitterAPIurl = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=";

// Twitter 'Screen Name'
// **** CHANGE THIS ****
static final String screenName = "Insert_Username_Here";

// Tweets to return
// **** CHANGE THIS, if needed ****
static final int tweets2Return = 1;

// Final URL will look like this (@ is your sreen name/return tweets):
// https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=@@@&include_rts=1&count=@
static String tweeterURL = twitterAPIurl + screenName
        + "&include_rts=1&count=" + tweets2Return;

static String twitterToken = null;
static String jsonTokenStream = null;
static String jsonFeed = null;
static String tweetJSON = null;

TextView twitterText;

// ////////////////////////////////////
// onCreate - Let's get the GUI going
// ////////////////////////////////////
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    twitterText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tweetFeed);

    // Call first AsyncTask
    new loadTwitterToken().execute();
}

// ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// AsyncTask - First, let's get our Token for oAuth (from Twitter)
// If you need oAuth help: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/oauth/faq/
// ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
protected class loadTwitterToken extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Integer> {

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params) {

        //As of this writing, Twitter says, "We do not currently expire access tokens."

        try {
            DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(
                    new BasicHttpParams());
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(
                    "https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token");

            String apiString = twitterAPIKEY + ":" + twitterAPISECRET;
            String authorization = "Basic "
                    + Base64.encodeToString(apiString.getBytes(),
                            Base64.NO_WRAP);

            httppost.setHeader("Authorization", authorization);
            httppost.setHeader("Content-Type",
                    "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8");
            httppost.setEntity(new StringEntity(
                    "grant_type=client_credentials"));

            InputStream inputStream = null;
            // Let's send to web
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            // Our response
            inputStream = entity.getContent();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            String line = null;

            // Will look like this:
            // {"token_type":"bearer","access_token":"AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABiQTgAAAAAACGie2o%2Bm7jNnxw8txVG99c1wAU8%3DmZq7qrX8JZpDFrgYyh5gLtOkJhQ7BvPD6bZ0ssitjg"}

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }

            jsonTokenStream = sb.toString();

            // onPostExecute likes to get a parameter passed to work right.
            // Just passing something.
            return 1;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("loadTwitterToken",
                    "doInBackground Error:" + e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {

        // Extract Token from JSON stream
        try {
            JSONObject root = new JSONObject(jsonTokenStream);
            twitterToken = root.getString("access_token");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("loadTwitterToken", "onPost Error:" + e.getMessage());
        }

        twitterText.setText("Got Token!");
        // Now that we have a oAuth Token, lets get our JSON feed from twitter.
        // We call it from here to make sure the Token has been received already.
        new loadTwitterFeed().execute();
    }
}

// ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// AsyncTask - Download Twitter Feed w/Token as authorization
// //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

protected class loadTwitterFeed extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Integer> {

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params) {
        BufferedReader reader =null;
         try{
            DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(
                    new BasicHttpParams());
            HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(tweeterURL);
            httpget.setHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + twitterToken);
            httpget.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

            InputStream inputStream = null;
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

            inputStream = entity.getContent();
            reader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"), 8);
            return null;
         } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    finally{
        if (reader != null)
            try {
                reader.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
        return null;

    }

         protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            try{
            JSONObject resultObject = new JSONObject(result);
            org.json.JSONArray tweetArray = resultObject.getJSONArray("results");
            for (int t=0; t<tweetArray.length(); t++) {
                JSONObject tweetObject = tweetArray.getJSONObject(t);
                sb.append(tweetObject.getString("from_user")+": ");
                sb.append(tweetObject.get("text")+"\n\n");
            }
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Tweet", "Error retrieving JSON stream" + e.getMessage());
                jsonFeed = sb.toString();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }   

             }
        }
            /*String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }*/



    protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
        // Update GUI
        if (jsonFeed.length() > 0) {
            twitterText.setText(jsonFeed);
        } else {
             //I'd assume wrong Consumer Key/Secret if this happens.
            twitterText.setText("Nothing Returned");
        }       
    }
}
```

Activity_Main.xml

```
<ScrollView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
     android:id="@+id/tweetFeed"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Loading..." />


</ScrollView>
```

Comment: I think you forgot to close the `progressDialog` in the `onPostExecute`.. do you close it somewhere else?

Comment: If you want much feedback I suggest you trim the MainActivity.java code in the question.Just trim the code to the deserialization and rendering related methods (Because according to you pulling the JSON is not the issue). The more pleasant to read, the more feedback ;)

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to close the ProgressDialog in `onPostExecute` method.
just do this  `pd.dismiss();` in `onPostExecute` like this.

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {

    pd.dismiss();

    // Extract Token from JSON stream
    try {
        JSONObject root = new JSONObject(jsonTokenStream);
        twitterToken = root.getString("access_token");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("loadTwitterToken", "onPost Error:" + e.getMessage());
    }

    twitterText.setText("Got Token!");
    // Now that we have a oAuth Token, lets get our JSON feed from twitter.
    // We call it from here to make sure the Token has been received already.
    new loadTwitterFeed().execute();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that @Priyanka. I've made strides in the code. I've found that I needed to change the XML TextView to ListView and drop the ScrollView. The only problem I'm having now is getting the R.java file to create an android.R.id.list, but my ListView id seems fine: "android:id="@android:id/list" Could anything else be causing it not to generate?

Comment: @reekdev when R.java file is not created than probably the error is in res folder.Check all .xml files if any error is there , also check your imports packages is there any package name 'android.R' remove it and if you use 'android:id="@android:id/list' means implicit android list than you should extends your class with ListActivity.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @Priyanka! I've made a few updates to the code. Again, it still doesn't crash or show errors, but I get as far as the status telling me "Got Token!" So it has authorized properly, but stops there. Can you tell if I set up the parse properly to output a list of tweets from my updated java? It should be the last blocks in the file. I appreciate your help so far. I can tell I'm close.